# Write to LIST from a DATA EXTENSION

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, data-extract

I am trying to pull subscriber information from a Data Extension, and then add it into a custom list.

I understand that the ideal process is to create a data extract, then import the CSV into the list.

However, I am wondering if there is a way to do it without the data extract?

Is there a way to use a SQL query to do it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two ways to go about it -

1. Using Data Extract and the Import (as you described)
2. Writing an SSJS activity. You can read from a DE and write to a List

SQL doesn't allow writing to a list